# Construct a quadrilateral ABCD whose sides are given assuming that the diagonal AC bisects the angle A.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

The question is from Kiselev's Geometry Book 1, exercise 220. I am not even sure from where I should start the construction.

When analyzing the problem, I tried to use the fact that the diagonal BD is divided by the diagonal AC in the ratio of the segments AB and AD since AC is the bisector, but I doubt it can be used to facilitate the construction since the diagonals are not given segments. The chapter introduces the method of reflection and translation, which I could not apply to the problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where did you get Kiselev?

Comment: Sorry, did not know that Givental translated it into English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that the chapter is on reflection, and we have angle bisectors, so is there a natural reflection to use?

**Hint:** WLOG $AB > AD$. Find a point $D^*$ on $AB$ and a point $C$ such that $AD = AD^*$ and $ CD = CD^*$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the insight. I have proceeded by marking D* on AB, found C from D* and B by the distance of DC and BC respectively, then finally found D from A and C. Is my construction correct? I just wanted to double check before accepting the answer.

Comment: @Taxxi Yes, that is what I had in mind. Can you write that up as an answer and then accept your own answer?

Comment: I can, but is there any particular reason behind it? This is almost the answer itself, and minor explanation of the construction is in the comment, so I think other people will benefit from this answer much more.

Comment: @Taxxi Complete answers are often preferred to hints, or at least that's what some  people in the community think. While I tend to fall in the camp of "go work it out from the hint, I'm not spoon-feeding", I also understand the flilpside of "Sometimes the person giving the hint doesn't do a good job of it. Or sometimes the hint just doesn't work".

Comment: Well, it was a very gentle and insightful hint so I think it would work with other people as well :)